# Heroku Flask App: Where to place wsgi.py?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, procfile

Trying to follow best practices for a Flask app running in Heroku so I'm moving things from app.py to working with blueprints.

The current directory structure is as follows:

```
--root
  --application
    --admin_blueprint
    --another_blueprint
    --wsgi.py (app = create_app())
    --__init__.py (this has def create_app, which handles creating my app)
  --migration
  --Procfile
  --requirements.txt
  --runtime.txt
  --config.py
  --manage.py
```

This is **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

...

def create_app():
    app = Flask(...)
...
    return app
```

and this is wsgi.py

```
from application import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the Procfile correctly, this is what I previously had when I had `app.py` and `wsgi.py` in my root directory and it was working fine on Heroku:

```
web: gunicorn app:wsgi
```

I've tried some of these:

```
web: gunicorn application:wsgi
web: gunicorn application.wsgi
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application application:wsgi
web: gunicorn application.wsgi.py
web: gunicorn "application.wsgi.py"
web: gunicorn "application/wsgi.py"
```

`flask run` works because I've exported `FLASK_APP=application.wsgi.py`

Thank you.

Comment: can you try `web: gunicorn application.wsgi --log-file -`?

Answer (score -1):

Use `application.wsgi:app`

`application.wsgi` (the part before the colon) instructs  `gunicorn` how to resolve the module.

and `app` (the part after the colon) gives the name of the WSGI application declared in the resolved module.

`:app` can be omitted and `gunicorn` defaults to looking in the module for a WSGI application with the name `application`.